# Custom class preventing loop exit when condition is met

Tags: python, while-loop, break, python-3.8

I am trying to break out of the outer while loop when the user inputs no (with any capitalization; I use the upper function). Currently, when the user inputs a "no" the while loop is run through again and if you enter "no" again then the while loop exits.

The issue is related to the Course class that is defined above the "main program". To fix this I created a separate "main program" that initializes the Course class.

I am confused as to why this occurred and was wondering if some clarification could be provided.

Running on Python 3.8.6

```py
class Course(object):
    # init method or constructor that creates a Course object
    def __init__(self, name, number, section, term_year, students):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.section = section
        self.term_year = term_year
        self.students = students
    
    #methods to edit specific course object attributes:    
    #edit the course name   
    def edit_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
    #edit the course number
    def edit_number(self, number):
        self.number = number
    #edit the course section
    def edit_section(self, section):
        self.section = section
    #edit the course term and year
    def edit_term_year(self, term_year):
        self.term_year = term_year
    #edit the course number of students
    def edit_students(self, students):
        self.students = students
   
    #methods to display the course object attributes
    #display all attributes
    def display_course(self):
        return( self.name+" "+ self.number + " " + self.section + " " +self.term_year+ " " + str(self.students))
    #display the course name
    def display_course_name(self):
        return( self.name)
    #display the course number
    def display_course_number(self):
        return( self.number)
    #display the course section
    def display_course_section(self):
        return( self.section)
    #display the course term and year
    def display_course_term_year(self):
        return( self.term_year)
    #display the number of students
    def display_course_students(self):
        return( self.students)
    #function to delete the course object
    def delete_course(self):
        del self

from Course import Course

Courses = []
loop = True
while loop:
    print(loop)
    #store the number of courses the user would like to add
    number = int(input("How many courses would you like to add? "))
    #iterate through the number of courses the user would like to enter
    if number > 0:
        for x in range(number):
            print(x)
            #store user input for each course
            name = input("Enter course name: ")
            number = input("Enter course number: ")
            section = input("Enter course section: ")
            term_year = input("Enter course term and year: ")
            students = input("Enter number of student for course: ")
            print("\n")
            
            #store each course into an array
            Courses.append([name,number,section,term_year,students])
    
    answer = input("Would you like to add anymore courses?").upper()
    print(answer)
    while True:
        if answer in ('YES','NO'):
            break
        else:
            answer = input('Incorrect option. Type "YES" to add more courses or "NO" to continue": ').upper()
    
    if answer == 'NO':
        loop = False
        break
    print(loop)
print(Courses)
```

The current output looks like this:

```
True
How many courses would you like to add? 0
Would you like to add anymore courses?no
NO
[]
True
How many courses would you like to add? 0
Would you like to add anymore courses?no
NO
[]
```

Comment: What casue `[]` to be printed? It looks like an empty list.

Comment: [This code doesn't reproduce your problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAlIH.png) It's possible this code is being called from other code that you haven't included in your post. Please [edit] your question to ensure that the [mre] you posted actually reproduces the problem. This link should help narrow down the source of the error [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I created and empty loop then printed it  after the while loop. I just added it to the code

Comment: @EmilyEhrlich The code you shared with us works well. The output you share comes from different code (I think)

Comment: @balderman I found the issue. I had a class defined above which created this issue, although I am not sure why it did this?

Comment: @EmilyEhrlich without reading the code we cant tell ..

Comment: @balderman I updated the question and content to what I need clarification in.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your issue after copy pasting your code and using a similar python version.

Similar to what @balderman mentioned, where did you print an empty list? I think some lines of code is missing from your answer.

```sh
$ python test.py
True
How many courses would you like to add? 0
Would you like to add anymore courses?NO
NO
```